# Integer equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the values in $\mathbb{N}^+$ of $q$ and $r$ such that the equation

$$r=\frac{q^{r-1}-1}{q-1}$$

has solutions on the integers.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked 5 or 6 examples? Do you know the rule for the sum of a (finite) geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any natural $q,r\ge 2$ we have
$$q^{r-1}-1=(q-1)(q^{r-2}+q^{r-3}+\ldots+1)$$

So the equation can be written
$$r=q^{r-2}+q^{r-3}+\ldots+1$$

Since there are $r-1$ terms in the RHS and each term is a positive integer, these terms must be $1$, except one, that must be $2$.

This implies that $q=2$, $r=3$.

Answer (score 2):

You want $1+q+q^2+\cdots + q^{r-2}=r$. Subtract $r-1$ from both sides:

$$(q-1)+(q^2-1)+\cdots + (q^{r-2}-1)=1$$

So $q-1$ is a divisor of $1$, so $q=2$ and $r-2=1$ or $r=3$.